# Expected value of inverse product of multinomial

Tags: statistics

Let $\mathbf{X} \sim Multinomial(n, \mathbf{p})$ where $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ are vectors of length $d$. Is there a closed form or an efficient way to compute 
$E\left( \frac{1}{X_1+1}\frac{1}{X_2+1}\cdots\frac{1}{X_d+1}  \right)$?

This problem arises in computing a conditional Poisson likelihood, but when 0 counts are unobserved/truncated. I have a recursive algorithm to compute this expected value, but it is too slow for one case when $n=88$ and $d=11$. I've resorted to computing via Monte Carlo but I keep thinking there has to be something more efficient.